# Laravel 8.1 how to make seeder of user table

Tags: database, laravel

I am trying to seed the user table but I am facing some issues can someone guide me where I am missing.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;


class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'name' => Str::random(10),
            'email' => Str::random(10).'@example.com',
            'password' => Hash::make('password'),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you shere issue?

Comment: Does this not work?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this using eloquent instead of the DB class with an existence check too:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // Seed test user 1
        $seededAdminEmail = 'admin@admin.com';
        $user = User::where('email', '=', $seededAdminEmail)->first();
        if ($user === null) {
            $user = User::create([
                'name'                           => 'Admin',
                'email'                          => $seededAdminEmail,
                'password'                       => Hash::make('password'),
            ]);
        }

        // Seed test user 2
        $user = User::where('email', '=', 'user@user.com')->first();
        if ($user === null) {
            $user = User::create([
                'name'                           => 'User',
                'email'                          => 'user@user.com',
                'password'                       => Hash::make('password'),
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the below line

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
```

The complete code look like

```
namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeders.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'name' => Str::random(10),
            'email' => Str::random(10).'@gmail.com',
            'password' => Hash::make('password'),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think, I just missing this line
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

this will help me to generate the seeder, thanks.